# Add JavaScript to a node form

Tags: 7, nodes, forms, javascript

I'm trying to add a custom JavaScript file to the forms to create or edit a node.

I've tried `mythemename_preprocess_page()`, `hook_form_alter()` and  `theme_content_type_node_form()`. They seem to pick up the page I am on, not the form in Drupal's Overlay with the form in it.

Obviously I want the JavaScript code to fire only when I'm actually on the form. So just putting it in a `onReady` function in a JavaScript file loaded on every page won't suffice.

This is the code I am using on the *template.php* file.

```php
function zeilschepen_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'node-accommodation-form':
      $form['#after_build'][] = 'zeilschepen_after_build';
      break;

    case 'views_exposed_form':
      if (isset($form['field_country_value'])) {
        $form['field_country_value']['#attributes'] = array('placeholder' => array(t('Land...')));
      }
      break;
  }
}

function zeilschepen_after_build($form, &$form_state) {
  $theme_path = drupal_get_path('theme', variable_get('theme_default', NULL));
  drupal_add_js ("$theme_path/js/test.js");
  return $form;
}
```

This is the content of the *test.js* file.

```js
(function ($, Drupal, window, document, undefined) {
  Drupal.behaviors.test = {
    alert('test');
  }
})(jQuery, Drupal, this, this.document);
```

How can I correctly add JavaScript code in a node form?

Comment: Alas... I've tried the method you linked. I've tried it in my template.php and did an echo $form_id. It echo's the forms on my page but not the form_id of the overlaying node form

Comment: are you using `attached`?

Comment: I'm not seeing the correct $form_id to begin with. So there's no use making a switch for a $form_id that doesn't exist.

Comment: first, don't use echo, use watchdog or dpm.  Second, use hook with form id in hook name.

Comment: I've edited my post to show the setup in my template.php. I want to add some js in my node-accommodation-form. I'm using echo's just to see if something is actually happening in there. I never get to see the 123 nor getting an error because $path doesn't exist in the after_build function.

Comment: using echo simply isn't reliable. If it works, it tells you sth. If it doesn't, it means nothing.

Comment: Noted. I've updated my post. If everything should work correctly it should include test.js now when I come across node-accommodation-form and the test.js should alert "test". But it doesn't. So I can only conclude that test.js is not being added. I can't find test.js in my page source either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This:

```
node-accommodation-form
```

Is the **HTML ID** of the form, found in `$form['#id']` (confusing I know). You need the **internal ID**, which is

```
node_accommodation_form
```

As in:

```
function zeilschepen_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'node_accommodation_form':
```

Using `#attached`, as mentioned in comments, is far preferable to `drupal_add_js()` when you get to that part.

As an aside, you may find coming back to your code later on a bit easier if you separate out your form alters like so:

```
function MYMODULE_form_node_accommodation_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Logic specific to the accommodation node form, no need to check form ID.
}
```

Also, as noted in another answer, theme hooks are only run when the theme is actually in use. So if you're using the admin theme for your node edit forms, your code will never run. If that's the case, you need to move the logic to a module.

Answer (score -1):

I think **hook_form_alter()** will help you. Try this:

```
   function yourmodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
     if($form_id == "your form id") {
       drupal_add_js('your js file');
     }
    }
```

Comment: It should be `#attached` form property, not `drupal_add_js`

Comment: @Mołot its right..

Comment: It's not a module, though. I've tried it in my template.php and did an `echo $form_id`. It echo's the forms on my page but not the form_id of the overlaying node form.

Comment: you can use it in your template file..

Comment: See my edit above your comment.

Comment: you can find the form id by inspecting the form.

Comment: I know. But if I want to create a switch in my form_alter I should be able to see the form_id. Since it's not echoing the form_id I can only assume that the form isn't going through the form_alter() function.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use [hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) function. place this function in the `template.php` and print the `$form_id`, So now you can get the ID of the `add/edit` form.

Now you must use [drupal_add_js](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) function to load that Javascript file.

```
function THEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
      if($form_id == "YOUR_FORM_ID")
                drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') . '/JS_DIRECTORY/mytheme.js');
```

This code loads `mytheme.js` from `JS_DIRECTORY` of your theme folder.

Comment: It should be `#attached` form property, not `drupal_add_js`

Comment: @Mołot that's right